# UK tourist Visa wait times

Tags: usa, uk, standard-visitor-visas

Me and my wife are traveling to the UK from USA on Sep 18th. We have a biometric appointment with Seattle consulate on Aug 29th. In total there are roughly 13 business days before we travel. Looking at standard Visa wait times, it's roughly 15 days before confirmation, so there can be a risk. I wanted to check what people have done in the past for this situation.

- Should we convert it to priority visa?
- Should we go through a local agent?

Comment: You have to obviously assume the worst case but me and other people I know got it within 8-9 working days except one person I know who got it after a month or so. All of us applied from Germany and the waiting times seemed similar.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the processing times from the GOV website:

[image]

I have not been in this situation, but just in case I recommend applying for priority. But as there is a 55%+ processing rate, it is your choice.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you are cutting it a bit close for comfort. Did you make sure that there are no other holidays in the 13 business days for the UKVI office? You should also account for +1 or 2 days for your application to start processing after the bio-metric appointment and to get your passport back after the visa decision. It can also happen that you don't get your passports back together on the same day - in our case, the family passports came 5 days after mine just because they were dispatched in separate lots.

I would advise to go for the priority processing just to secure your visit and be on the safer side - I assume your tickets are already booked.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to convert to premium processing if the biometric center we chose does not have the priority processing available?

Answer (score 1):

The aim is to handle all applications within 30 days of submission however this is natually subject to case-by-case basis. In my personal opinion, a visa application I oversaw took about five weeks to be decided, in which it was granted. This was primarily due to previous immigration trouble six months earlier.

If your tickets are already booked then it really is playing it risky as the official UKVI website specifically encourages travellers not to book tickets or reservations until the issue of their visas solely for the reason that not all visas can be handled within the specified time frame.

There's not a lot many of us can tell you other than to check the estimated processing times posted above and to just wait for them. Chances are you'll get them quickly but these are always subject to change.